# How to access files which are stored outside project in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, file

I am trying to display files from the local directory using javascript. Is this possible? As earlier i used the files which were inside the project using this format : `Url : './files/'`. Worked pretty well with javascript. Now i want to access files from outside the project eg. `Url : "d:/"` But javascript has some restrictions on that. How can i load files from d: drive using javascript?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
URL = 'd:/content/abc.pdf'; /// ??????
});
```

Comment: your question is not that clear though. if you mean to access the filesystem of the client -> no chance.

Comment: Yes. but there might be some alternate solutions?

Comment: yes, if the client uploads the needed file. thats about the only chance you have

Comment: He does. I am saving that in d: directory and then trying to access it using javascript!

Comment: then you need to save it into an directory where the document is accessible by your webserver, and you can read it through http://yourserver/document.pdf

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, this is not possible. When running in the context of a web page, Javascript cannot read files which are not available on the web.

Comment: Good to know that. Will have to find some alternate solution then!

Answer (score 0):

You can't load files from local computer with JavaScript. Otherwise any website would be able to steal info from user. 
The only way is to ask a user to upload a file (maybe with ajax) and take it from your server than.